# MVC4 \ how to add .png & .js etc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, png

I'm a newbie in Web Development -
Opened VS2012, with new MVC project (their default project is started).

I don't find a way to add my .png files (Shoud I locate them under Content>Themes>Bast>Image?), same goes for .js - tried drag & drop, tried "Add" - I know it is REALLY REALLY basic - but how do I add my files (not regular class and everything)

Comment: What's the problem with `Add -> New item`?

Comment: Should be as easy as @FSou1 said.  I usually put my images under Images in the root of the application.  JS files I usually place under Scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my projects, I have Content/Images/pnghere and Scripts/jshere. You simply right click the desired folder, hover over "Add" and click new Item. Choose .js file in the case of your scripts.

If you don't want to work with that, you could always just use file explorer and literally copy/paste the file in the desired spot. Then in VS, refresh the solution explorer and click "Show All Files". When the pasted file shows up (should be colorless and faded), right click it and select "Include in Project" at which point it will become colored and be ready to use.

Comment: Thanks for all the advises. My "New Item"\"existing item" seems to be disabled in all levels (sln, proj, folder).

Comment: Wait, you're not running the solution while you're trying to add an iterm are you? Because if you're debugging, you can't add/delete files.

Comment: woow, I'll check that when I arrive home!

Comment: You did have the program debugging while trying to modify the folder? I only realized that was a possibility because I've done it myself so many times. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the mvc project in VS2012 solution explorer and select Add -> Existing item.., you can browse and select .png file or .js file and any other file you want to add to the project. To add files to any sub folder under the project, you do the same by right clicking on the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this image, hope it helps:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the advises. My "New Item"\"existing item" seems to be disabled in all levels (sln, proj, folder).